# Conflict between R Tools (Mikhail-Arkhipov.r) and vscode-R

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use R on vscode, so I followed the command on vscode and downloaded what it requires me to download. However, when I try to write some codes in R, vscode tells me that there is a conflict between the two extensions.[This is the image that contains all the error]

Error 1:
Unable to start Microsoft.R.Host process. Exception: R Services broker process did not start. Reason: 'Unknown error (0x80008096)'. Exit code: -2147450730

Error 2:
The R Tools (Mikhail-Arkhipov.r) extension is enabled and will have conflicts with vscode-R. To use vscode-R, please disable or uninstall the extension.

I tried to stwich my DNS, reinstall R, vscode, and those two extensions, but non of the way works.

Comment: This is more like a vscode than a proper R issue

Comment: Did you follow the directions and disable one of the two extensions?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: @Tim Roberts I disableded one of them and it did work out. However, I wonder if this disable will bring any negative consequence to my coding project? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @GuedesBF Is there any way to revolve this conflict? Thank you very much!

Comment: Honestly, you resolve the conflict by disabling one of the extensions.  They both serve similar purposes.  You aren't going to miss it.